# Simulate mouse click without moving the cursor

Tags: c++, windows, function, winapi, button

I wrote an application that detects all active Windows and puts them into a list.

Is there a way to simulate a mouseclick on a spot on the screen relative to the Windows location without actually moving the cursor?

I don't have access to the buttons handle that is supposed to be clicked, only to the handle of the window

Comment: Wrong question. Here is the answer to the question you should have asked instead: [UI Automation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee684009.aspx). For a live demo check out the [Inspect](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318521.aspx) tool that comes with the SDK.

Comment: It seems odd that you want to push buttons in some random list of windows. Maybe you are looking for `SetForegroundWindow`

Comment: @Barmak Shemirani, I have multiple Windows of clients that need to be monitored at the same time on the screen, the program is supposed to put every Window with a certain title in a list and lay up to 12 of them out in a certain pattern on each screen. This is working so far, I just need an additional function that clicks a button in a 3rd party application every n minutes to open these windows in the first place.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Is there a way to simulate a mouseclick on a spot on the screen relative to the Windows location without actually moving the cursor?

To answer your specific question - NO.  Mouse clicks can only be directed where the mouse cursor actually resides at the time of the click. The **correct** way to simulate mouse input is to use [`SendInput()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646310.aspx) (or [`mouse_event()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646260.aspx) on older systems). But those functions inject simulated events into the same input queue that the actual mouse driver posts to, so they will have a physical effect on the mouse cursor - ie move it around the screen, etc.

[How do I simulate input without SendInput?](http://i1.blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2010/12/21/10107494.aspx)

> SendInput operates at the bottom level of the input stack. **It is just a backdoor into the same input mechanism that the keyboard and mouse drivers use** to tell the window manager that the user has generated input. The SendInput function doesn't know what will happen to the input. That is handled by much higher levels of the window manager, like the components which hit-test mouse input to see which window the message should initially be delivered to.

[When something gets added to a queue, it takes time for it to come out the front of the queue](http://i1.blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2014/02/13/10499047.aspx)

> When you call Send­Input, **you're putting input packets into the system hardware input queue**. (Note: Not the official term. That's just what I'm calling it today.) This is the same input queue that the hardware device driver stack uses when physical devices report events.
>
> The message goes into the hardware input queue, where the Raw Input Thread picks them up. The Raw Input Thread runs at high priority, so it's probably going to pick it up really quickly, but on a multi-core machine, your code can keep running while the second core runs the Raw Input Thread. And the Raw Input thread has some stuff it needs to do once it dequeues the event. If there are low-level input hooks, it has to call each of those hooks to see if any of them want to reject the input. (And those hooks can take who-knows-how-long to decide.) Only after all the low-level hooks sign off on the input is the Raw Input Thread allowed to modify the input state and cause Get­Async­Key­State to report that the key is down.

The only real way to do what you are asking for is to find the `HWND` of the UI control that is located at the desired screen coordinates.  Then you can either:

1. send [`WM_LBUTTONDOWN`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645607.aspx) and [`WM_LBUTTONUP`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645608.aspx) messages directly to it.  Or, in the case of a standard Win32 button control, send a single [`BM_CLICK`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775985.aspx) message instead.
2. use the [`AccessibleObjectFromWindow()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd317978.aspx) function of the [UI Automation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee684009.aspx) API to access the control's [`IAccessible`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318466.aspx) interface, and then call its [`accDoDefaultAction()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318470.aspx) method, which for a button will click it.

That being said, ...

> I don't have access to the buttons handle that is supposed to be clicked.

You can access anything that has an `HWND`.  Have a look at [`WindowFromPoint()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633558.aspx), for instance.  You can use it to find the `HWND` of the button that occupies the desired screen coordinates (with caveats, of course: [WindowFromPoint, ChildWindowFromPoint, RealChildWindowFromPoint, when will it all end?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20101230-00/?p=11873)).

Comment: Thanks, didn't know getting the button handle was this simple, I'll give it a try!

Comment: @ColdZer0: It would be easy, if there were a native window backing the button control. This is not generally the case. Web browsers usually don't use native controls. Neither do Qt applications. Both of these support UI Automation, though.

Comment: @IInspectable: True. If the actual `HWND` at the coordinates is not a Win32 button then you can't use `BM_CLICK`. However, you would still have a real `HWND`, and sending `WM_LBUTTON...` to it at those coordinates would trickle down as needed to any non-windowed controls it happens to hold. But, if it supports UI Automation, that helps too, since you would be able to enumerate its child controls that are not otherwise accessible.