# Click Button using WindowFromPoint() and SendMessage()

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, button, window

I'm trying to use WindowFromPoint() to retrieve the handle of a button and then use SendMessage() to click the button.

I don't get an error with my code but the button isn't getting clicked either..
Basically nothing happens.

I have already confirmed that the coordinates point directly to the location of the button.

I have also tried ChildWindowFromPoint() but it didn't change anything.

Here is my code:

```
std::cout << "Assigning parent Window..." << std::endl;
for (std::list<Window>::iterator i = mainDetector.getWindowList().begin(); i != mainDetector.getWindowList().end(); ++i)
{
    if (i->getTitle().find(windowTitle) != std::string::npos)
    {
        parentWindowHandle = (HWND)i->getHandle();

        std::cout << "Parent Window assigned." << std::endl;

        break;
    }
}

std::cout << "Clicking button..." << std::endl;

buttonHandle = ChildWindowFromPoint(parentWindowHandle, registerButtonLoc);
SendMessage(buttonHandle, WM_LBUTTONDOWN, NULL, NULL);
SendMessage(buttonHandle, WM_LBUTTONUP, NULL, NULL);
```

Hope someone tell me where my mistake is..

Comment: You cannot use `SendMessage()` to send input messages. Use UI Automation instead.

Comment: @andlabs Unless there's a UIPI issue, why not?

Comment: Are you getting correct handle in `buttonHandle`?

Comment: @immibis Focus issues. If the button doesn't have the focus, it won't receive input messages.

Comment: @CodyGray As I understand it, if the button doesn't have the focus, the window manager won't send it keyboard input messages. That has nothing to do with what happens if someone else sends it input messages, or with non-keyboard input messages.

Comment: It's easy for it to get confused. Sometimes it works, usually it doesn't. Not surprising that the person is having this problem. Windows wasn't designed for this. UI Automation is the solution.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I'll give UI Automation a try!

Comment: As I told you in [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34846256/65863) to your [other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34846165/) on this same topic, if the button is a standard Win32 button, you can use the `BM_CLICK` message instead of the `WM_LBUTTON...` messages.  Also, since you are using `ChildWindowFromPoint()`, make sure `RegisterButtonLoc` is expressed in **client coordinates** that are relative to the parent window you are searching. Otherwise, use `WindowFromPoint()` instead, which operates on **screen coordinates**.